# "Banger" as name for sausage

Tags: word-meaning, british-english, irish-english

I was surprised a bit today, when one of dishes for lunch today were bangers.

I never heard this name before...

I would like to know is this name common in other english speaking countries or is it specific to Ireland only?

By the way, maybe you know why they call it like this - I found it rather strange in relation to verb "to bang"

Comment: Recumbent upon a bed of mash, now there's a right kip! It's not Irish English so much as British. See [**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bangers_and_mash) for the droolworthy details.

Answer (score 4):

These are pork sausages you can order probably at any pub in UK. I used to have them either as a part of 'Traditional English Breakfast' or as 'Bangers and Mash' in England, all over London and Kent specifically. What to the origin of the term, Wiki suggests it has indeed something to do with the verb 'to bang':

> The term "bangers" is attributed (in common usage in the UK) to the fact that sausages made during World War I, when there were meat shortages, were made with such a high water content that were more liable to pop under high heat when cooked.

Comment: If you order a "banger" in the States, it unlikely anyone will know what you mean.  Also, if you order your American breakfast with "sausage", prepare for disappointment.

Comment: @Andrew Depends where you order it. There is real sausage made and cooked throughout the country. I've had German-style in central PA, for instance, that rivals anything I've eaten in Würzburg.

Comment: @P.E.Dant agreed, I tried to edit my comment to add "at a typical American diner", where they look more like [this](http://cookdiary.net/wp-content/uploads/images/Breakfast-Sausage_7799.jpg).